# How to translate this Octave code to Julia?

Tags: julia, octave

I want to make a logistical map in Julia and I am having difficulties. I already know how to do it in Octave, how could I turn this code to Julia? My difficulty is mainly in the "map [i,:]" part.

```
#Creates a vector of initial conditions and "r"
x=rand(150,1);
r=(2.51:.01:4);

#Transpose the r
r=r';

#Makes 300 times the product of each element of r for each element of x
for i=1:300
x=r.*x.*(1-x);
end

#Makes 200 times the product of each element of r for each element of x and stores each value of x on line i of the "map" matrix
for i=1:200
x=r.*x.*(1-x);
map(i,:)=x;
end

#Plots each column of the map for each element o r
plot(r,map,'.')
```

Comment: What `map(i,:)=x` is intended to do?

Comment: Sorry, now I realized that I left an "...and" without completing the comment. ```map(i,:)=x``` stores each value of x on line i of the "map" matrix. Then, I use this to plot each point of x by r.

Comment: Maybe you will understand it better by looking at the type of graph generated [map generated with Octave with x by r](https://imgur.com/a/k1tlejF)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't written julia in a while so there may be more efficient ways of doing this now, but here is a more or less direct equivalent to your octave code.

```
using PyPlot

x = rand( 150, 1 );
r = reshape( 2.51:.01:4, (:, 1) );

for i in 1:300
    global x
    x = r .* x .* (1 .- x);
end

Map = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 200, 150);

for i in 1:200
    global x, Map
    x = r .* x .* (1 .- x);
    Map[i:i,:] .= transpose(x);
end

for i in 1:length(r)
   plot( r, Map[i,:], "." )
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Tasos! I tried to run your code here and it didn't work. It gives an error: "LoadError: Cannot convert String to series data for plotting"

Comment: Anyway, seeing your code showed me some things that finally made it possible for me to achieve my goal. Your treatment with the matrix was fundamental to me understand my mistakes. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoãoVitorVieiraFlauzino My pleasure. Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned this was tested / written for julia v1.6.1. Btw, may I suggest you edit your post's title to something that would be more useful to future users searching the site with a similar problem? (e.g. the name of this function and the fact you're trying to plot it would be useful information to include)

Comment: Why make `x` and `r` matrices instead of vectors? I think this is the wrong thing to do. Also, I don't think it's a good idea to put the individual plots along rows. Instead of just translating the code, why not show a better way? Right now this is not idiomatic Julia.

Comment: @DNF yes, I wouldn't disagree. In fact, the octave code isn't particularly 'idiomatic' for octave either (including the plots in the rows, as you say). Having said that, in this kind of scenario, I feel there is value in providing a 'direct equivalent', since that helps a person starting with the language to appreciate the specific differences. That and I wouldn't really even know what is considered 'idiomatic' julia these days, hah. (I swear, every time I look julia up it's gone and changed again).

Comment: Yeah, it's a personal preference thing. I never like answering directly, instead I like saying "you're asking the wrong question", hehe. BTW, I don't think Julia has changed that much the past couple of years.

Answer (score 7):

Starting here:

```
#Creates a vector of initial conditions and "r"
x=rand(150,1);
```

This isn't a vector, but a matrix of size 150x1. If you want a vector, write:

```
x = rand(150)
```

As for this:

```
r=(2.51:.01:4);

#Transpose the r
r=r';
```

It's a bit unclear, but I think you want a vector of the same length as `x`, in that case you should *not* transpose it, because that turns it into a 1x150 matrix. So instead write

```
r = 2.51:0.01:4
# or, maybe better
r = range(2.51, 4; length=length(x))
```

Next:

```
#Makes 300 times the product of each element of r for each element of x
for i=1:300
x=r.*x.*(1-x);
end
```

Instead of creating a new variable `x` at each iteration, update `x` in-place, and remember to dot all the operators here:

```
for i in 1:300
    x .= r .* x .* (1 .- x) # dot everything
end
```

I don't really understand what's going on with your code here, it seems to just do more of the same, a bit arbitrarily. More importantly, you try to update `map` before you have defined it. Furthermore, you shouldn't really use the name `map` because that's the name of an important built-in function in Julia.

```
#Makes 200 times the product of each element of r for each element of x and stores each value of x on line i of the "map" matrix
for i=1:200
x=r.*x.*(1-x);
map(i,:)=x;
end
```

Alternative. Pre-define a matrix, call it something other than `map`, and store the information column-wise, not row-wise, since that it much more efficient, both in Matlab/Octave and Julia

```
M = similar(x, length(x), 200)
for i in 1:200
    x .= r .* x .* (1 .- x)
    M[:, i] .= x  # use square brackets, not parens
end
```

BTW: your code becomes much more readable if you put in spaces between operators. Cramming everything together gives a messy appearance. Also, use indentation for readability. And drop all the semicolons.

Comment: The code OP posted is valid octave code, not julia code. Effectively they're asking for a translation of that code from octave to julia. I see this was not 100% clear in the pre-edited version though.

Comment: Oh, was it? I saw that it used `#` for comments, which made me conclude it must be Julia code. I thought Octave syntax was identical to Matlab (by design), and Matlab uses `%`. This changes how I should phrase the answer, but I think it mostly still works, haven't tested it though.

Comment: Yeah, Octave supports both % and # for comments.